# Multi edge graph in GraphStream

Tags: java, graphstream

How can I create an undirected graph, where 2 vertices are connected with multiple parallel edges? I've seen a similar question here [Displaying Parallel Edges in Graphstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23634855/displaying-parallel-edges-in-graphstream) , but this didn't help. I still had only one edge between 2 vertices.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The answer provided in the link seems to correctly solve the problem, do you have a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the issue? Or maybe you just forgot to add the `gs-ui` jar?

Comment: I was using System.setProperty() in wrong place. Yes you're right, problem was correctly solved in that link. Thank you!