# Exception on Multigraph in graphstream

Tags: java, graphstream

I am working to show two edges on two nodes if there are more than one edge.
I am following this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23634855/displaying-parallel-edges-in-graphstream). But I am facing an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   scala/collection/convert/WrapAsScala  at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
>   org.graphstream.ui.view.Viewer.newGraphRenderer(Viewer.java:349)  at
>   org.graphstream.graph.implementations.AbstractGraph.display(AbstractGraph.java:753)
>     at
>   org.graphstream.graph.implementations.AbstractGraph.display(AbstractGraph.java:747)
>     at com.h2Database.app.ahd.main(ahd.java:18) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.convert.WrapAsScala
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 6 more

my code is :

```
import org.graphstream.graph.*;
import org.graphstream.graph.implementations.*;
import org.graphstream.ui.view.Viewer;

public class ahd {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Graph graph = new MultiGraph("Test");
        System.setProperty("org.graphstream.ui.renderer", "org.graphstream.ui.j2dviewer.J2DGraphRenderer");
        graph.addNode("A");
        graph.addNode("B");

        graph.addEdge("1", "A", "B", true);
        graph.addEdge("2", "A", "B", true);

        Viewer viewer = graph.display();
    }
}
```

Any idea, why I am facing this ? It seems that in given example this issue is resolved.

Comment: Please specify which version of `gs-core` and `gs-ui` you are using.

Comment: @Yoann 1.3 , latest version

Answer (score 1):

[GraphStream](http://graphstream-project.org) v1.3 [is comprised of](http://graphstream-project.org/download/) three `jar` files:

```
$ ls -1 lib/*1.3.jar
lib/gs-algo-1.3.jar
lib/gs-core-1.3.jar
lib/gs-ui-1.3.jar
```

`J2DGraphRenderer` and its inner classes may be found in `gs-ui-1.3.jar`:

```
$ jar tf lib/gs-ui-1.3.jar | grep org.graphstream.ui.j2dviewer.J2DGraphRenderer
org/graphstream/ui/j2dviewer/J2DGraphRenderer$$anonfun$render$2.class
org/graphstream/ui/j2dviewer/J2DGraphRenderer.class
org/graphstream/ui/j2dviewer/J2DGraphRenderer$.class
org/graphstream/ui/j2dviewer/J2DGraphRenderer$$anonfun$render$2$$anonfun$apply$1.class
org/graphstream/ui/j2dviewer/J2DGraphRenderer$$anonfun$removeRenderers$1.class
org/graphstream/ui/j2dviewer/J2DGraphRenderer$$anonfun$render$1.class
org/graphstream/ui/j2dviewer/J2DGraphRenderer$$anonfun$removeRenderers$3.class
org/graphstream/ui/j2dviewer/J2DGraphRenderer$$anonfun$removeRenderers$2.class
```

Verify that `gs-ui-1.3.jar` is in the classpath at runtime:

```
$ javac -cp .:lib/* ahd.java 
$ java -cp .:lib/* ahd
```

[image]

Note that [*classpath syntax is OS-dependent*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4528438/230513).

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem. What fixed it for me is to upgrade from 1.3 to 2.0. Note that the ui package has been renamed to `gs-ui-swing` (or `-javafx` or `-android`).